# AutoMigrate is not updating Constraints - MySQL

Tags: go, go-gorm

AutoMigrate is not adding constraint **UNIQUE** for an existing column and that column doesn't have any duplicates.

Note. nothing shown using Debug mode.

any idea?

Comment: Possibly prevented by [not changing existing columns](http://gorm.io/docs/migration.html): _WARNING: AutoMigrate will ONLY create tables, missing columns and missing indexes, and WON’T change existing column’s type or delete unused columns to protect your data._

Comment: Mark's comment is right. Consider using something like [gormigrate](https://github.com/go-gormigrate/gormigrate) to have more control on your migrations.